# I am using TRACE in MFC, but it is not working(no output). why?

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-debugging

```
TRACE("This is a TRACE statement\n");
OutputDebugString("dd");
for(int x=0; x<pDoc->r_length; x++)
{
    TRACE("The value of x is %d\n", x);
    for(int y=0; y<pDoc->c_length; y++)
    {
        TRACE("x = %d and y = %d\n", x, y);
        data=pDoc->m_OpenImg[x][y]+100;//circle image +100

        //choose method for Saturation.
        if(data>255)
        {
            pDoc->m_ResultImg[x][y]=255;//save the output value
        }
        else
        {
            pDoc->m_ResultImg[x][y]=data;//save the output value.
        }
    }
}
```

I'm studying MFC in this semester. I want to see debug output with TRACE. (I found TRACE in MSDN) 
This is part of my MFC code. I put TRACE into for loop. Other than the issue TRACE and OutputDebugString is not working correctly, the other part of the code works fine. I want to see debug output. Help me please.

Comment: is this a debug build? Are you looking at the right output pane in VS?

Comment: This is MFC code. The member function name is void CHelloView::OnAbc(){}. I used visual studio c++ 6.0. This function run and debug but In debug, output pane is empty.

Comment: Are you looking at the Debug tab of the output window ? You should have lots of stuff like `Loaded 'ntdll.dll', no matching symbolic information found.` before **your** debug output in that tab.

Comment: could you tell me how to load 'ntdll.dll' ??
and I inserted breakpoints into TRACE() but didn't stop. is it right?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `TRACE` or `OutputDebugString`, the output does not go to the normal command window. Instead it goes to a special debug output stream. If you run the program from within Visual Studio, you can see this stream in the Output pane. If you are running it independently (in a command window, or by double-clicking on the icon) you need a special utility that can monitor the stream. One such utility is [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx).

Note that `TRACE` only works in Debug builds, while `OutputDebugString` works in any build type.